# Javascript asynchronous calls stepping on one another

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using AHAH (as outlined here http://microformats.org/wiki/rest/ahah) to make two calls to populate HTML on a page. The calls happen after the document is ready and are fired off one after another. The result, every time, is the first call gets overwritten with the last calls response. So I'll have two of the same chunks of HTML on the page instead of two unique pieces of code. Sometimes the first call doesn't even get to evaluate it's call back and thus remains empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the exact code on that page, it's not surprising, as the example there uses a single global variable to store the XMLHttpRequest being made. So there's no way it can work for more than one simultaneous request: calling the function a second time overwrites the `req` with a new one, causing the `req` read by `ahahDone` to be the wrong request.

If you want to allow this you'll have to make `req` a local variable (by declaring it `var` in `function ahah()`), and pass it with the `target` to the `ahahDone()` function. Or just do it inline:

```
function Element_loadHTML(element, url) {
    var req= null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req= new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            req= new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHttpRequest');
        } catch() {}
    }
    if (!req) {
        element.innerHTML= 'Browser does not support XMLHttpRequest';
        return;
    }
    element.innerHTML= 'Loading...';

    req.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if (req.readyState===4)
            element.innerHTML= req.status===200? req.responseText : 'Error '+req.status;
    };
    req.open('GET', url);
    req.send(null);
} 

Element_loadHTML(document.getElementById('appdata'), 'appdata.part.html');
Element_loadHTML(document.getElementById('foo'), 'bar.part.html');
```

The stuff with the browser sniffing and trying to execute script tags is hopeless and broken; don't use it. It's not good practice to be loading `<script>` element content into the page.

Comment: PREFECT, I don't know why I didn't see that before. Thank you! Also, I'm not using the script tag execution portion. It really is just a bad idea.